# three.js group vs scene.add individual

Tags: three.js

I made a website with three.js for graphical website.

It's concept is universe that has so many texts.

To spread text, there is two method.

First is put every mesh to group, and spread it like this.

(In this example, spread star instead of text)

```
group = new THREE.Group();

for ( let i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {
  var starsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  var star = new THREE.Vector3();
  star.x = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 100 );
  star.y = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 100 );
  star.z = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 100 );

  starsGeometry.vertices.push( star );
  var starsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

  var starField = new THREE.Points( starsGeometry, starsMaterial );

  starField.position.x = Math.random() * 150-80;
  starField.position.y = Math.random() * 180-100;
  starField.position.z = Math.random() * 1000;

  group.add(starField);
}
scene.add(group);
```

Put every meshes to group and add group to scene.

Second is just add to scene one for one like this.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {
  var starsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  var star = new THREE.Vector3();
  star.x = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 100 );
  star.y = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 100 );
  star.z = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 100 );

  starsGeometry.vertices.push( star );
  var starsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

  var starField = new THREE.Points( starsGeometry, starsMaterial );

  starField.position.x = Math.random() * 150-80;
  starField.position.y = Math.random() * 180-100;
  starField.position.z = Math.random() * 1000;

  scene.add(starField);
}
```

I wonder that what is difference between group and just scene add?

Is there any performance issue or anything else?

And I know that particles is similar with group, Is there any difference with above things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly the same speed. The group node transform should only get updated once per frame, which isn't a big deal.

Using a group may help you keep it organized also.. since later if you need to process just the things in that group, you have the list of them in group.children.

Comment: I got it. How about particles?

Comment: Also worthwhile to note — while these will be the same speed, both are going to be quite slow with 1000 geometries. It would be best to merge the geometries into one, to reduce draw calls.